# How to pass test data to obtain model predictions if onehotencoder applied to train data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am using Sklearn.preprocessing to preprocees (onehotencoder) the categorical data.

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
pre_loc_data1 = onehotencoder.fit_transform(pre_loc_data1.astype(str)).toarray()
print(pre_loc_data1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pre_loc_data1, pre_loc_target, test_size=0.2)
```

here X-train is now encoded data.
if i give the y_train data to model for prediction it's working fine.
because it is also encoded data.
but i want to use individual record as input to model to predict without encoding like below

```
(clf.predict(['Hyderabad / Secunderabad','0 Year(s) 8 Month(s)','android','java']))
```

how to give such type of data as input to model to test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The train and test data have to be in the same format, so you have to pass all your data through OneHotEncoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `onehotencoder` to the input (assuming `clf` is your trained model):

```
clf.predict(onehotencoder.transform([['Hyderabad / Secunderabad','0 Year(s) 8 Month(s)','android','java']]))
```